# zf2 authentication with doctrine2 - store only user id in session

Tags: php, authentication, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

is there a way to store only the user id in the session and get the user object from database on every request? I need a page, where the user can change his data. That way the shown user information would be updated and the user doesn't have to login again to see the changes. At the moment i use:

- Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService
- DoctrineModule\Authentication\Adapter\ObjectRepository
- DoctrineModule\Authentication\Storage\ObjectRepository

I know i could change the user data in my controller action with the following code, but i think the other way would be better.

```
$authService->getStorage()->write($updatedUser);
```

Comment: I'm confused, by default this is already the case. The 'id' is what is stored in the session and the user is [loaded on each request using that identity](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Authentication/Storage/ObjectRepository.php#L83)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! Of course only the id is stored in the session. It was a mistake of myself! :/